# How i can show rows that have inputed value in new table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, frontend

This is my table :

```
     <table id="products">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>quantity</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {% for pr in productlist %}
        <tbody id="t1" class="tbody">
            <tr class="test" data-index="pr.productid" style="border: none; border-collapse: collapse;">
          <td>
            {{ pr.productname }}
          </td>
          <td>
                <input class="prqty" id="prinp" type="number" placeholder="0" max="pr.numberqut" min="0" name="mylist">
              </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        {% endfor %}
       </table>
```

and this is result:

[image]

Here i append to new table:

```
<table id="here"></table>

<script>
    $('#here').html($('#products').clone().attr('id', 'newproducts'));
</script>
```

**My problem is that i don't know how can filters rows that have input value.**

i want this:

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can select all `.test` rows, convert to an array, and use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along with `querySelector` to check whether the first input's value is `0` ([or greater than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68513184/how-i-can-show-rows-that-have-inputed-value-in-new-table/68513250?noredirect=1#comment121087433_68513250)).

```js
const valid = $('.test').toArray().filter(e => e.querySelector('input').value != "0");
console.log(valid);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="products">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="t1" class="tbody">
    <tr class="test" data-index="pr.productid" style="border: none; border-collapse: collapse;">
      <td>
        {{ pr.productname }}
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="prqty"  type="number" placeholder="0" max="pr.numberqut" min="0" name="mylist" value="0">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test" data-index="pr.productid" style="border: none; border-collapse: collapse;">
      <td>
        {{ pr.productname }}
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="prqty"  type="number" placeholder="0" max="pr.numberqut" min="0" name="mylist" value="1">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Filter demo:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  const valid = $('.test').clone().toArray().filter(e => e.querySelector('input').value != "0");
  valid.forEach(e => $('#here').append(e));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="products">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="t1" class="tbody">
    <tr class="test" data-index="pr.productid" style="border: none; border-collapse: collapse;">
      <td>
        {{ pr.productname }}
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="prqty" type="number" placeholder="0" max="pr.numberqut" min="0" name="mylist" value="0">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test" data-index="pr.productid" style="border: none; border-collapse: collapse;">
      <td>
        {{ pr.productname }}
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="prqty" type="number" placeholder="0" max="pr.numberqut" min="0" name="mylist" value="1">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
<button>Filter</button>
<table id="here"></table>
```

Comment: How i can add to new table?

Comment: @hami Loop through the array and append each item with `append()`.

Comment: i am really new to JS, can you please help more?

Comment: @hami Sure. Use `valid.forEach(e => $('#here').append(e))`

Comment: I use this methods , but after click a button to append new table all rows append(even 0 rows that have input 0) and main table data cleaned and show white space

Comment: @hami I've updated my answer to show what it looks like (the second snippet).

Comment: Thanks, i can solve by your help , i change `('input').value != "0")` to `("input[id='pqty']").value > 0` but here one problem. when i click on filter button last data not updated and last rows cached. how to solve it?

Comment: Thank you i solved it. please edit your answer based on above comment.